# postgres trigger in golang using lib/pq

Tags: postgresql, go

Any working example of using postgres trigger in golang which takes rows modifies a column and sends it back. There is a notification framework but couldn't figure out how to return the modified rows

want to create this as a trigger function

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION trigger_set_timestamp()
RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
BEGIN
  NEW.updated_at = NOW();
  RETURN NEW;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: Your example doesn't seem to have anything to do with your question.

Answer (score 0):

Made it work like this

```
if addInsertTime {
    triggerFunc := fmt.Sprintf("CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION trigger_set_timestamp()\nRETURNS TRIGGER AS $$\nBEGIN\nNEW.%s = NOW();\nRETURN NEW;\nEND;\n$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;", "insert_time")
    fmt.Println(triggerFunc)
    if _, err := db.Exec(triggerFunc); err != nil {
        logrus.Error(err)
        return err
    }
  }

if addInsertTime {
    createTrigger := fmt.Sprintf("CREATE TRIGGER set_timestamp\nBEFORE UPDATE ON %s\nFOR EACH ROW\nEXECUTE PROCEDURE trigger_set_timestamp();", tableInfo.tableName)
    if _, err := db.Exec(createTrigger); err != nil {
        logrus.Error(err)
        return err
    }
}
```